# C++ linking custom .so libraries and then with JNI

Tags: c++, linker, java-native-interface, g++, shared-libraries

I have a problem linking C++ libraries and I could really use some advice.
I have two custom .so libraries, which I am using in my cpp project, which I am then linking to Java using JNI.

In my cpp project I am including the header files for the two libraries and JNI. Then I am creating an object file, like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -std=c++11 -fPIC -c my_file.cpp
```

The two includes specify the path to JNI libraries. I am using cpp11 and then a switch -fpic I found that may be necessary during creation of shared libraries.

Next I tried to link my object file: my_file.o with the two shared libraries like this:

```
g++ -fpic -L/<absolute path>/library1.so -L/<absolute path>/library2.so my_file.o -shared -o my_file.so
```

I am building a shared library which will be called from Java using JNI. I tried several different variations of assembling the linking parameters but none worked. I am further calling System.load() in Java on an absolute paths to my_file.so and library1.so
Currently I am receiving an error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /<absoulte path>/my_file.so: undefined symbol: <method from library 1>
```

I have read several post here about linking and required parameter order of libraries in order to ensure the correct linking and I have gone through much of g++ documentation, yet no matter how I order them and no matter what parameters I use, it does not seem to work. I will be greatfull for any advice as to how to link these files.

Comment: Typically you use `-L<path>` to indicate a path where shared libraries will be found, and then `-l<name>` to indicate libraries you wish to link, where the library filename is `lib<name>.so`.  So if your shared library is in /absolute/path/library1.so, you would use options `-L/absolute/path` and `-lrary1`.

Comment: You are right. Yet it did not change anything. Still got the same error.

Comment: Try to `System.load("rary1")` and "rary2" before you call `System.loadLibrary("my_file.so")`

Comment: Did not work either.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with some help.

Firstly, for those who do not know about the command "ldd" on linux, it shows the linked symbols (linked library dependencies). When I saw that my libraries weren't there I tried to rearrange the linking command.
I had to place the object file my_file.o before the other two libraries. Then I saw that ldd pointed out that the libraries were not found. I moved them to a system library and with some more symlinks everything worked. Thanks to everyone for their effort